# How to set defaultstate with markdown value in draftjs

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

How to set the defaultEditorState with a  mark down value. I am using react-draft-wysiwyg.
example.

```
const value = "Test Message :)↵↵Click This Link - link↵↵Link Url - link";
```

I have manage to set the defaultEditorState using the code below but its not rendering new line in this part "↵↵".

```
this.setState({
   editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(
     ContentState.createFromBlockArray(convertFromHTML(nextProps.value))
  )
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I just read the draftjs. I just change *createFromBlockArray* to *createFromText*

```
this.setState({
   editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(
     ContentState.createFromText(nextProps.value)
   );
});
```